# Matching entities in SQL Server to replace iterative Python script

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, edit-distance

I have a SQL (MS SQL Server) database of ~22 million companies (called `target_db` in my code). For example:

```
+-----------------------+----------------+-----------+
|     CompanyName       |    ReFcode     | ID_number |
+-----------------------+----------------+-----------+
| Mercedes Benz Limited | Germany        |     12345 |
| Apple Corporation     | United States  |     67899 |
| Aunt Mary Butcher     | United Kingdom |     56789 |
+-----------------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Then, I have another list of companies (called input in my example) and I would like to assign `ID_number` based on approximate company name match. The size of my sample is 1000 companies but can be much more.

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|      name          |    ReFcode     |
+--------------------+----------------+
| Mercedes Benz Ltd. | Germany        |
| Apple Corp.        | United States  |
| Butcher Aunt Mary  | United Kingdom |
| Volkswagen Gmbh    | Germany        |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

I wrote a script in Python that does the following for each of the companies in my sample:

1. Connect to the database and filter the `target_db` to only get the names that start with the same 3 letters, have similar length (+- 7 characters) and Soundex DIFFERENCE is 4
2. Calculate levenshtein with all possible matches (using fuzzywuzzy library)
3. Choose the match with the highest similarity

This worked mostly fine and accomplished the task in around 6 minutes. I did some profiling and noticed that 5 minutes and 30 seconds was spent on connecting to the DB (in every iteration of the loop), running query and fetching the results. The rest was calculating the similarity. Which I found quite surprising.

I thought that I could save time and improve performance by doing the process entirely in SQL, so I started writing this query:

```
SELECT distinct input.name, 
                target_db.CompanyName, 
                input.Country, 
                input.ReFcode, 
                [dbo].[edit_distance](input.name, target_db.CompanyName) as levenshtein
FROM dbo.Sample as input
JOIN dbo.Company as target_db
on 
    (input.ReFcode = target_db.Refcode and 
    LEFT(input.name, 3) = LEFT(target_db.CompanyName, 3) and
    SOUNDEX(input.name)=SOUNDEX(target_db.CompanyName))
WHERE ABS( LEN(input.name) - LEN(target_db.CompanyName)) <= 7

ORDER BY levenshtein asc
```

Then I would take the match with the lowest `EditDistance` (Levenshtein) below a certain threshold. This works but the process now is taking almost 30 minutes. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: Don't know exactly why it's so much slower, but you can add a ROW_NUMBER to apply the *lowest EditDistance* filter within the Select. And poor *Aunt Mary Butcher* will not be found, using NGrams is probably a better way: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/

Comment: If you are still interested in getting a review of this code, can you post an execution plan for both versions (before and after) and provide the before code so we can look at that as well?

Comment: One red flag: you mentioned "connecting to the database on every iteration of the loop". Definitely don't do this. Your Python might be fine if you just maintain a single connection. Please post your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what your old code was it is hard to pinpoint where the slowdown came from. That being said, here are some things you're doing in your query that are going to make it slower:

1. Using a UDF prohibits parallel plans. You could throw 1000 CPUs at this problem and it would still only use one of them. If computing this is too complex to do inline, then use an inline table-valued function instead, which enables parallelism.
2. `JOIN`ing on functions (UDF or otherwise) performs really poorly. SQL Server has no cardinality estimate for `LEFT(input.name, 3)`, but it does for `input.name`. If at all possible find another way to do this join (a suggestion is below). Similarly, filtering in a `WHERE` clause has the same restrictions.

To address this, I would likely change your join to just be on `RefCode` - this gets you a good hash match (probably), but will increase your granularity. Then, make your `edit_distance` function table valued, like so

```
SELECT <<stuff>>
  FROM dbo.Sample input
    INNER JOIN dbo.Company target_db
      ON input.ReFcode = target_db.Refcode
    CROSS APPLY dbo.edit_distance( input.name, target_db.CompanyName ) levenshtein
```

Then, inside of `dbo.edit_distance` I would include the `LEFT`, `SOUNDEX` and `LEN` calculations (`LEN` calc would also be better if you did `LEN( input.name ) - LEN( targetdb.CompanyName ) BETWEEN -7 AND 7`).

If levenshtein returns some score, then you could do something like this to only get the best score per input name. Alternatively if you want them all, then have it return everything and do whatever calculations the consuming app needs.

```
SELECT name,
       CompanyName,
       Country,
       RefCode,
       levenshtein_score
  FROM ( SELECT input.name,
                target_db.CompanyName,
                input.Country,
                input.ReFcode,
                levenshtein.levenshtein_score,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY input.name
                                    ORDER BY levenshtein.levenshtein_score ASC ) RowNumber
           FROM dbo.Sample input
             INNER JOIN dbo.Company target_db
               ON input.ReFcode = target_db.Refcode
             CROSS APPLY dbo.edit_distance( input.name, target_db.CompanyName ) levenshtein ) ComputedLevenshteinScores
  WHERE ComputedLevenshteinScores.RowNumber = 1
  ORDER BY levenshtein ASC;
```